# SET IDENTITY_INSERT not working

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Are there any circumstances when `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` will not work if executed using entity framework and SQL Server, though it will work from SSMS on the same database using the same credentials (`sa`)

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext oContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

ExecuteSql(oContext, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Albums ON");
ExecuteSql(oContext, "INSERT INTO dbo.Albums ([Id], [Name], [Description]) VALUES (-2, 'album1', 'album1')");
```

This throws an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Albums' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

However, when I run these same 2 lines in SSMS, the identity insert works fine.

Using:

- SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition (64 bit) version 13.0.4202.2, running on localhost
- Entity Framework version 6.0.0.0*

The `ExecuteSQL` method is as follows:

```
public static void ExecuteSql(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext c, string sql)
{
     var entityConnection = (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection)c.Connection;

     DbConnection conn = entityConnection.StoreConnection;
     ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;

     using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
     {
         cmd.CommandText = sql;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Putting `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON` in the same Query, as next:-

```
ExecuteSql(oContext, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Albums ON; 
INSERT INTO dbo.Albums ([Id], [Name], [Description]) 
VALUES (-2, 'album1', 'album1')");
```

Comment: Unbelievable.Wonder why this makes a difference.

Comment: The connection otherwise can be returned to the connection pool between statements, and reset.  You can also explicitly open the DbContext.Database.Connection to force it to stay open.